# Printing all lines matching a string and a set number of lines after that string

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

I want to extract relevant data of a traffic junction and it's connections from a log file. Example log:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
       Stage Suffix for Offset Optimizer  1                                     
Double Cycle Initially ?  N   Force Single / Double Cycling status ? N          
Double Cycle Group       00   Double Cycle Ignore ? N                           
Allow Link Max Saturation N   Link Max Sat Override N                           
Stages       1   2   3   4                                                      
Fixed        N   N   N   Y                                                      
LRT stage    N   N   N   N                                                      
Skip allowed N   N   N   N                                                      
Ped stage    N   N   N   N                                                      
Ped invite   N   N   N   N                                                      
Ghost stage  N   N   N   N                                                      
Offset authority pointer   0     Split authority pointer   0                    
Offset opt emiss weight  000     I/green feedback inhibit  N                    
                                                                                
                                                                                
Bus Authority   00  ACIS node  00000                                            
                                                                                
Bus Mode - Central extensions  N   Local extensions  N  Recalls  N              
           Stage skipping      N   Stage truncation  N Cancels   N              
Bus Priority Selection - Multiple buses  N  Queue Calculation  N                
Hold recall if faulty N  Disable recall  N  Disable long jtim  N  Real Cancel N 
                                                                                
Bus recall recovery type      0  Bus extension recovery type  0                 
Offset Bus authority pointer  0  Split Bus authority pointer  0                 
Bus skip recovery             0  Skip importance factor       0                 
Bus priority status   OFF                                                       
LRT sat 1  000  LRT sat 2  000  LRT sat 3  000                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
                  PEDESTRIAN FACILITIES                                         
Ped Node                   N        Num Ped Wait Imp Factor     000             
Ped Priority               0        Max Ped Priority Freq        00             
Ped Lower Sat Threshold  000        Ped Upper Sat Threshold     000             
Max Ped Wait Time        000                                                    
               PEDESTRIAN VARIABLE INVITATION TO CROSS                          
Allow Ped Invite       N            Ped Priority Auto           000             
Ped Invite Upper Sat 000 Prio Level 1    2    3    4                            
Max Ped Priority Smoothed Time     000  000  000  000                           
Max Ped Priority Increase Length    00   00   00   00                           
                  CYCLE TIME FACILITIES                                         
Allow Node Independence    N        Operator Node Independence    0             
Ghost Demand Stage         N        Num Ghost Assessment Cycles  15             
Upper Trigger Ghost       04        Lower Trigger Ghost           0             
                                                                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C                                     
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
       Stage Suffix for Offset Optimizer  1                                     
Double Cycle Initially ?  N   Force Single / Double Cycling status ? N          
Double Cycle Group       00   Double Cycle Ignore ? N                           
Allow Link Max Saturation N   Link Max Sat Override N                           
Stages       1   2   3                                                          
Fixed        N   Y   Y                                                          
LRT stage    N   N   N                                                          
Skip allowed N   N   N                                                          
Ped stage    N   N   N                                                          
Ped invite   N   N   N                                                          
Ghost stage  N   N   N                                                          
Offset authority pointer   0     Split authority pointer   0                    
Offset opt emiss weight  000     I/green feedback inhibit  N                    
                                                                                
                                                                                
Bus Authority   00  ACIS node  00000                                            
                                                                                
Bus Mode - Central extensions  N   Local extensions  N  Recalls  N              
           Stage skipping      N   Stage truncation  N Cancels   N              
Bus Priority Selection - Multiple buses  N  Queue Calculation  N                
Hold recall if faulty N  Disable recall  N  Disable long jtim  N  Real Cancel N 
                                                                                
Bus recall recovery type      0  Bus extension recovery type  0                 
Offset Bus authority pointer  0  Split Bus authority pointer  0                 
Bus skip recovery             0  Skip importance factor       0                 
Bus priority status   OFF                                                       
LRT sat 1  000  LRT sat 2  000  LRT sat 3  000                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
                  PEDESTRIAN FACILITIES                                         
Ped Node                   N        Num Ped Wait Imp Factor     000             
Ped Priority               0        Max Ped Priority Freq        00             
Ped Lower Sat Threshold  000        Ped Upper Sat Threshold     000             
Max Ped Wait Time        000                                                    
               PEDESTRIAN VARIABLE INVITATION TO CROSS                          
Allow Ped Invite       N            Ped Priority Auto           000             
Ped Invite Upper Sat 000 Prio Level 1    2    3    4                            
Max Ped Priority Smoothed Time     000  000  000  000                           
Max Ped Priority Increase Length    00   00   00   00                           
                  CYCLE TIME FACILITIES                                         
Allow Node Independence    N        Operator Node Independence    0             
Ghost Demand Stage         N        Num Ghost Assessment Cycles  15             
Upper Trigger Ghost       04        Lower Trigger Ghost           0
```

I can already extract the first relevant line using the following Bash script:

```
grep SCN* LOG.TXT > JUNCTIONS.txt
```

Which creates a list of all the junctions like so:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
SCN DD1301       At Glasgow Road - Argyll Road - Cart Street                    
SCN DD1351       At Kilbowie Road - Chalmers Street
...
```

However, I want to extract the lines immediately after each link title, down to the final link of the node just before a large amount of whitespace and without capturing anything from Stage Suffix onwards until the next link.

Is there a way to modify my BASH script to include an additional number of lines after each matching instance it finds?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate an example of the desired output for your input example so that contributors can exactly understand what you want to achieve. Also, please include whether the number of lines is fixed or variable, and if the "stopping pattern" is simply a certain number of empty lines (are they empty as in no characters, or only "visually empty" meaning they can contain whitespace/tabs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
sed -n '/^SCN/,/^\s*$/p' LOG.TXT
```

It prints the lines between two patterns (and the lines that contain them):

- 'SCN' appearing at the start of a line (`^SCN`)
- and a blank line containing 0 or more white space characters (`^\s*$`)

and outputs the following:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C
```

Comment: Thanks @YetAnotherUser, I edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

In your case, an `awk` program comes to mind:

```
awk '/^SCN/{f=1} !NF{f=0} f' LOG.TXT > JUNCTIONS.TXT
```

This will

- set a flag `f` to `1` when the line starts with `SCN`
- reset the flag to `0` when an empty line is found (in this case, we allow "visually empty" lines by imposing the condition that no text fields are found, rather than that no characters at all are present)
- print the current line only when the flag is `1`

Somewhat simpler, using address ranges instead of explicit flags:

```
awk '/^SCN/,/^[[:space:]]*$/' LOG.TXT > JUNCTIONS.TXT
```

The output for your example would be:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           

SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C
```

The first example would not print separating blank lines.